# How to return the contents of a HTML file without executing the code?

Tags: php, html, css, email

I have two files, an HTML file which contains the layout and basic CSS for the email and a PHP file which actually sends the email. I was wondering if there was any way to require or include the HTML file as the message to be sent from the PHP script.

For example:

HTML

```
<h1>A title</h1>
```

PHP

```
mail("email", "subject", require('htmlfile'));
```

I have tried something like this but it just puts the contents of the HTML file into the flow of the PHP script. Is there any way to have the HTML file just return text which I can save to a variable or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can inline your php code in your html file or put your php file into variable so that you can get that value and pass to $message.

Comment: `$body = file_get_contents('yourhtmlfile.html');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mail("email", "subject", file_get_contents('file_name.html'));
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) states: `Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function.`

It gives an example of how to do this, you would need to modify your code to fit your needs though.

```
return.php
<?php

$var = 'PHP';

return $var;

?>

noreturn.php
<?php

$var = 'PHP';

?>

testreturns.php
<?php

$foo = include 'return.php';

echo $foo; // prints 'PHP'

$bar = include 'noreturn.php';

echo $bar; // prints 1

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will work for sure.

```
Your PHP file:
"msg.php"
<?php

   $message = "This is a sample message";

?>

Your HTML file with a mail() function:

"mail.php"
<?php

   require ('msg.php');
   mail("sample.yahoo.com", "sample subject", $message);

?> 

<html>
<head>
<body>
<h1>A title</h1>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```